# How can I make angular-formly deal with an unknown number of model fields that are nested in an array property

Tags: angular-formly

**UPDATED**:  I've updated the JSBin to fix the indices problem and to create formly fields for each property rather than attempting to pass the properties array into a formly template.  This would allow me to define custom and property-specific validators if need be.  I still don't know if this is the right approach though so some guidance would be welcome.

I have a model structure like the following whereby each object can have a different number properties:

```
[
  {
    prop1: boolean,
    prop2: String,
    ...
    properties: [
      {
        key: String,
        value: String,
        description: String
      },
      ...
    ]
  },
  ...
]
```

It should be pretty straight forward to pass the array of objects to a formly type template and have formly iterate over each object's properties array (right?).  I think the tricky part would be wanting to validate each item in the properties array - with *separate* validators.

Any thoughts on how I might do that?  The keys are well-defined so I could, in theory, create some angular service that maps a key to a `validators` object but i'm not clear how to tell formly about it.

I have a working JSbin [here](http://jsbin.com/weyeva/edit) that does sorta/kinda work, but it feels dirty to me.

I want to think there's a way to put an `ng-repeat` in a wrapper template but looking at the formly code, it does not appear that formly can handle multiple `<formly-transclude>` elements in a wrapper - even though it can handle multiple wrappers so maybe there's a way to do it with multiple wrappers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually (aside from some styling issues that can/should be resolved with css), I think your implementation is fine. I would recommend you do exactly what you're doing by generating the field configuration based on the model before you hand it to angular-formly.

Comment: No worries and thanks again @kentcdodds.  You've helped me out a bunch this year and I appreciate it.  What do you think about making an example of this for the formly site?  Or not worth it?

Comment: Seems a bit specific of a use case I think for an example. Thanks though!